# stuck on weatherApp for freecode challenge

Tags: javascript, openweathermap

this time I'm stuck on js for weatherApp. I'm using one of the tutorials on yt doing step by step (with my twist) but the backbone of the code is without my twist. But

```
function getWeather(loc) {
var lat = Math.floor(loc.split(",")[0]);
var lon = Math.floor(loc.split(",")[1]);

var weatherApiUrl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon + "&appid=5a1518c003259fdaa613a1aa78664ff9&";
 console.log(weatherApiUrl);
$.get(weatherApiUrl, function(weather){

  var temperature = weather.main.temp;
  var description = weather.weather[0].description.toUpperCase();
  var pressure = weather.main.preure;

  console.log(weather);
```

I cannot log weather variable to console, not sure why.

Comment: what's the last `&` for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you included the **jQuery library** correctly,  and see the following:

```js
function getWeather(loc) {

  /* I'm not sure this is correct...
  var lat = Math.floor(loc.split(",")[0]);
  var lon = Math.floor(loc.split(",")[1]);
  RATHER USE: */

  // API will already float to .toFixed(2), so no need to do Math stuff...

  var latLon = loc.split(","),
      lat = latLon[0].trim(),
      lon = latLon[1].trim();

  var weatherApiUrl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon + "&appid=5a1518c003259fdaa613a1aa78664ff9";


  $.get(weatherApiUrl, function(weather) {

    var temperature = weather.main.temp;
    var description = weather.weather[0].description.toUpperCase();
    // var pressure = weather.main.preure; // preure? WTF?

    console.log(weather);

  });

}


getWeather("45.815399, 15.966568");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: there must be something wrong with my codepen, i included jQuery in settings but it kinda works earlier for IP API but not for weather. I copied the exact same code to cssdeck.com and $("#temp").append(weather.main.temp); works there, but not in codepen. Anyway i used ur suggestion about longitude and latitude and thanks for ur time and help!

Comment: If you were running it on CodePen did you make sure you loaded CodePen over http rather than https? If you loaded it over https it wouldn't be able to connect to the API over http as your browser would prevent the request.

Comment: That was the exact issue, thank you very much on clarifying this for me.